# Workaround for copying folder in subversion to a different directory

Tags: svn

I'm trying to copy a folder from repository A to a different repository B. 
Of course I'm getting the error:

```
Source and destination URLs appear not to point to the same repository.
```

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Developers@SVN mailing list thread: ["Would branching across repositories be theoretically possible?"](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/subversion-development/aqv7D0lcckE/9D6d-xrdtfMJ).

Comment: Already seen that. This is more of a talk about future features, I was looking for a straightforward guide.